# pgRouting results to LINESTRING geometry type

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, geometry

I am doing some routing queries, using pgRouting's second version of pgr_trsp function.
What I can't do effectively yet is storing the results. That is, I want to able to store in a table:

1. either the actual result from pgRouting (not very useful anyway),or
2. geometry(LINESTRING) data type, derived from the
   pgr_costresult (can be used in spatial queries).

Here is the bit of code I tried (and failed :P):

```
--Test function to convert pgr_costresult to geometry.
--Input arguments are the arguments of the pgr_trsp function, i.e. edge id's and relational position.
--TODO: do the same function work for arbitrary points.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fm_pgr2geom(edge1 integer, pos1 float8, edge2 integer, pos2 float8)
    RETURNS geometry AS $$
 --We have to do a routing query. And declare a cursor for it
DECLARE resc CURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM pgr_trsp (
        'SELECT * FROM th_2po_4pgr',
        $1, $2, $3, $4, false, true);
    doline geometry[];
    temp_point geometry;
    geom geometry;
    temp_rec RECORD;
BEGIN
--Find startpoint and append to doline
    doline := array_append(
        doline,ST_Line_Interpolate_Point((SELECT map.geom_way FROM th_2po_4pgr map WHERE map.id = $1),$2));
--Append the rest of nodes
    FOR temp_rec IN SELECT * FROM pgr_trsp (
        'SELECT * FROM th_2po_4pgr',
        $1, $2, $3, $4, false, true) LOOP
            doline := array_append(
            doline, (SELECT nodes.geom FROM nodes WHERE nodes.id = temp_rec.id1));
    END LOOP;
--Append the endpoint
    doline := array_append(
        doline,ST_Line_Interpolate_Point((SELECT map.geom_way FROM th_2po_4pgr map WHERE map.id = $3),$4));
geom := ST_MakeLine(doline);
RETURN geom;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

This piece of code is supposed to return a geometry (linestring) with all the points of the result. However the actual result is only a 2-point linestring.
Do you know any convenient way I can achieve either or both? I think second option is preferable, since I doubt postgresql tables can store complete pgr_costresults and Geometry types can be used for spatial analysis.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Can you edit your question to show what queries you're performing, what you've already tried in terms of "storage", what the results of that were, and why you're trying to store the results at all? That is, tell us some specific details about your needs and your situation. Showing SQL queries and indicative results is usually appropriate for this sort of question. Also, note that you don't need to add your signature - its already on every post.